# How to make a orbital launch tube work?

Tags: launch, rockets, propulsion, reuse, physics

Normal rockets would not work in a pressurized tube, but could a stage be made for the diagonal launch tube to save fuel and weight? Can the bottom stage be nuclear powered?

Unlike the piston launch that is only designed to lift a rocket out of the ground, this would be diagonal, ride on a rail and have a compression plate on the first stage.

Comment: What is a diagonal launch tube?

Comment: @Uwe I don't know but hope to be alive when its working.